# Exclude kubernetes namespaces from metric collection by datadog agent

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, datadog

After installing datadog chart (version=3.1.3) on EKS, I need to limit some of namespaces from metric collection. I'm using `containerExclude` to limit the namespace scope. The values I'm using is as follows:

```
datadog:
  site: datadoghq.eu
  clusterName: eks-test
  kubeStateMetricsEnabled: false
  kubeStateMetricsCore:
    enabled: false
  containerExclude: "kube_namespace:astronomer kube_namespace:astronomer-.* kube_namespace:kube-system kube_namespace:kube-public kube_namespace:kube-node-lease"
  prometheusScrape:
    enabled: true
    serviceEndpoints: true
    additionalConfigs:
      - autodiscovery:
          kubernetes_annotations:
            include:
              prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
            exclude:
              prometheus.io/scrape: "false"

clusterAgent:
  enabled: true
  metricsProvider:
    enabled: false

agents:
  enabled: true
```

Looking at the pod environment variables, I see this is being passed to agent correctly:

```
DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE: kube_namespace:astronomer kube_namespace:astronomer-.* kube_namespace:kube-system kube_namespace:kube-public kube_namespace:kube-node-lease
```

However I see see scrape logs from those namespaces:

```
2022-09-26 13:48:38 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:127 in LogMessage) | openmetrics:f744b75c375b067b | (base.py:60) | Scraping OpenMetrics endpoint: http://172.20.79.111:9102/metrics
2022-09-26 13:48:38 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:127 in LogMessage) | openmetrics:c52e8d14335bb33d | (base.py:60) | Scraping OpenMetrics endpoint: http://172.20.22.119:9102/metrics
2022-09-26 13:48:39 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:123 in LogMessage) | openmetrics:ba505488f569ffa0 | (base.py:66) | There was an error scraping endpoint http://172.20.0.10:9153/metrics: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.20.0.10', port=9153): Max retries exceeded with url: /metrics (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd271df8190>, 'Connection to 172.20.0.10 timed out. (connect timeout=10.0)'))
2022-09-26 13:48:39 UTC | CORE | ERROR | (pkg/collector/worker/check_logger.go:69 in Error) | check:openmetrics | Error running check: [{"message": "There was an error scraping endpoint http://172.20.0.10:9153/metrics: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.20.0.10', port=9153): Max retries exceeded with url: /metrics (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd271df8190>, 'Connection to 172.20.0.10 timed out. (connect timeout=10.0)'))", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", line 1116, in run\n    self.check(instance)\n  File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/openmetrics/v2/base.py\", line 67, in check\n    raise_from(type(e)(\"There was an error scraping endpoint {}: {}\".format(endpoint, e)), None)\n  File \"<string>\", line 3, in raise_from\nrequests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: There was an error scraping endpoint http://172.20.0.10:9153/metrics: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.20.0.10', port=9153): Max retries exceeded with url: /metrics (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fd271df8190>, 'Connection to 172.20.0.10 timed out. (connect timeout=10.0)'))\n"}]
2022-09-26 13:48:39 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:127 in LogMessage) | openmetrics:8e74b74102a3722 | (base.py:60) | Scraping OpenMetrics endpoint: http://172.20.129.200:9102/metrics
2022-09-26 13:48:39 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:127 in LogMessage) | openmetrics:e6012834c5d9bc2e | (base.py:60) | Scraping OpenMetrics endpoint: http://172.20.19.241:9127/metrics
2022-09-26 13:48:39 UTC | CORE | INFO | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:127 in LogMessage) | openmetrics:ba98e825c73ee1b4 | (base.py:60) | Scraping OpenMetrics endpoint: http://172.20.64.136:9102/metrics
```

Those services belong to `kube-system` which is excluded. But I see that these metrics belong to Prometheus [Openmetrics]. Do I have to apply similar setting in `prometheusScrape.additionalConfigs`?

Comment: Same issue here :/. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to add `containerExcludeLogs` into your config

You can check out this flag in [their helm chart](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/datadog/values.yaml#L808C3-L808C23)